# Merge 2 pairs of tables from 2 databases. Beginner

Tags: mysql, merge

I have two MySql databases DB1 and DB2. Each of them has tables tbl1 and tbl2. These two tables have the same primary key (Column1). Tables in DB1 have N rows. I want to create new database and table, which will look like:

```
DB1.tbl1.Col1   | DB1.tbl1.Col2 | ... | DB1.tbl1.ColK | DB1.tbl2.Col2 | DB1.tbl2.ColZ
    ...         |    ...        | ... |     ...       |    ...        |      ...   
DB2.tbl1.Col1+N | DB2.tbl1.Col2 | ... | DB2.tbl1.ColK | DB2.tbl2.Col2 | DB2.tbl2.ColZ
    ...         |    ...        | ... |     ...       |    ...        |      ...
```

But, I could not use MERGE as I need indexes in DB2.tbl1.Col1 in new table to be `DB3.tbl.Col1=DB1.tbl1.Col1, DB2.tbl1.Col1+N`.

I now how to do it on the side of client (on Python), but is it possible to do it via some MySql script on server side?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you not sure how to create the new table data e.g. with a `union all` or is it about how to create the new index?

Comment: First of all I am not sure how to make union. Second, how to create new index. Sorry, I am really not so good in SQL.

Comment: sorry now I'm confused by your edit

Comment: I have 2 databases from two sites. tbl1 of each database contains UserID and its email, address, phone and so on. tbl2 contains some information about user actions on the site. Now i want to have 1 table from both sites. I am ready to change UserIDs for second site just by adding number of users on site 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about?

```
create table DB3.tbl1 as
select * from (
  select
    DB1.tbl1.Col1,
    DB1.tbl1.Col2, ...
    DB1.tbl1.ColZ
  from DB1.tbl1
  union all
  select
    DB2.tbl1.Col1 + n
    DB2.tbl1.Col2, ...
    DB2.tbl1.ColZ
  from DB2.tbl1
)
```

could also replace the `+ n` by `+ ( select count(*) from DB1.tbl1 )`

Comment: Looks perfect, but I also need to merge tbl1 and tbl2 before...

Comment: Sorry, it was not in my question table. I've edit it.

Comment: using `union all` keeps duplicates where as using just `union` skip duplicates in tbl2.